# Как прочитать строку подключения к базе данных из конфигурационного файла в c#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Я создаю приложение для базы данный ms sql server. Строка подключения находится в конфигурационном файле app.config, методы работы с базой я хочу вынести в отдельный класс, чтобы потом обращаться к нему в обработчиках кнопок, событий в приложении.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как может выглядеть такой класс и как из него обратиться к конфигурационному файлу, чтобы прочитать строку подключения! Если можно на примере, очень нужно!

Конфигурационный файл выглядит примерно так:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="TestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var connection = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: спасибо! а как может выглядеть класс с методами работы с базой данных? не получается найти

Comment: Может выглядеть по-разному. Все зависит от вашей задачи

Comment: Если я указал ответ правильный - пометьте его галочкой. Укажите что это правильный ответ.